# Speeding up the boot process

Tags: debian, boot, performance

My system boots in approximately one minute.

How can I speed up the boot process?

It's Debian 10.

This is the output from `systemd-analyze`

```
Startup finished in 7.598s (kernel) + 53.454s (userspace) = 1min 1.053s
graphical.target reached after 53.437s in userspace
```

and graphics versions of processes in boot:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/7sz3tyf6tq96b38/plot.svg/file

What processes should I delete?

Comment: Are you using SSD or spinning hard disk? Do you want a graphical session? Have you looked at what's being started at boot?

Comment: It's fun to see concerns that 53 seconds is too long for a system to boot!  I think we'd need to see a listing of the processes it starts, and perhaps some description of the services that are important to you, in order to tell you what you don't need.

Comment: I use HDD. Of course graphical interface is a must.  I turned bluetooth service off. But the other services looks like critical so that's why i'm asking. When i was using windows 8 in this pc, it used to boots in 4-8 seconds. Don't you think 1 minute is too long? Also, i am open to your recommendations to which process should i delete. The only important thing for me is booting fast as it can without systematic problems.

Comment: I couldn't upload .svg file in here so i shared external link.

Comment: Windows was booting in 4-8 seconds because it wasn't actually booting, it was just coming out of hibernation. If you do a [full shutdown](https://www.isumsoft.com/windows-10/2-ways-to-perform-a-full-shutdown.html) and reboot it will take much longer. Booting in under a minute is pretty good!

Comment: No, it wasn't  in sleep mode. Computer was off and i turn on. And it used to boots in max 10 seconds. Numbers are not important. I mean, is it normal to boot in 1 min. in linux? Isn't it long?

Comment: Ben, Windows 7 and onwards "cheats" by sleeping (hibernating) when you ask it to shut down. Look up [windows fast startup](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+fast+startup) for further details on this, and how to disable it if you want to.

Comment: I get it. I didn't know this. Allright, so can i make things better in linux or are these concerns unneccessary?

Comment: You could choose Hibernate instead of Shutdown, if your system offers that option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My system boots in approximately one minute.
> How can I speed up the boot process?

and

> I use HDD

The most effective way to speed up a one minute boot (not that this is slow) is to replace the mechanical hard disk (HDD) with a solid state equivalent (SSD)

> It's Debian 10.

The default desktop environment in Debian is Gnome. You could replace it with a more lightweight option, e.g. LXDE.

**Further options**

Completely avoiding a full shutdown will reduce boot/restoration times: restoring from sleep will take only 2-3 seconds, but draws energy. Alternatively hibernation will not drain battery, but takes a bit longer. In both cases the advantage is, that your session is exactly restored as you left it, directly allows continuing work where you left it.

Comment: Okay, i get it. I note that SSD replacement. And can i do something with systemd-analyze ?

Comment: @ben The default desktop environment for Debian 10 is Gnome, you could go for a more lightweight version, e.g. LXDE. Use sleep or hibernate instead of shutdown (note that sleep draws energy, but you're back up in 2 secs).

Comment: @Fiximan add that as an answer and you'll get +1 from me (ping me...)

Comment: @roaima My understanding of SE U&L is more like making the comment part of your answer.

Comment: @Fiximan thank you. You would have been (and still would be) fine by me to add your own answer, as I'd neither mentioned GNOME vs LXDE nor (here, at least) Hibernate vs Shutdown :-)

Answer (score -1):

1. Run systemd-analyze blame
2. Disable the services you know you do not need

Comment: This is output. I don't know which is critical and not. Which one should i delete?                          31.633s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         14.594s ifupdown-pre.service
         11.550s ModemManager.service
          9.463s udisks2.service
          8.037s NetworkManager.service
          7.749s accounts-daemon.service
          7.001s dev-sda1.device
          6.560s fwupd.service
          5.582s wpa_supplicant.service
          5.578s systemd-logind.service
          5.575s rsyslog.service
          5.572s vboxdrv.service
          5.568s switcheroo-control.service

Comment: 5.564s alsa-restore.service
          5.368s avahi-daemon.service
          5.346s exim4.service
          2.739s networking.service
          2.239s apparmor.service
          2.174s systemd-udevd.service
          1.912s polkit.service
          1.324s gdm.service
          1.197s upower.service
          1.185s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service

Comment: Looks like you are already at the bare bones.